# Hyper-V/SCVMM 2012 VLAN ID's not working

Tags: vlan, windows-server-2012, scvmm, hyper-v-server-2012

I am having issues getting multiple VLAN's set up on my Hyper-V cluster.  Here is the scenario;  I need to have 2 separate (potentially more in the future) VLAN's to span across the Hyper-V environment.  So far I have set up a trunk to the Hyper-V hosts on the switch side of things.  Here is what the trunk config looks like;

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/20
 description TEST
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 10
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 5,10
 switchport mode trunk
```

Now, on the Hyper-V side of things I have created identical virtual switches across all hosts, named "Inside".

I have created the logical network for this "Inside" vSwitch, set up the VLAN's on the logical network and built the IP pools for each.  I will gladly post the configuration if that helps at all.

This is where the issue arises.  If I leave the VM NIC's untagged (no VLAN ID), they all seem to work fine, and connect to the VLAN 10 network like they should.  Once I tag the NIC then traffic to either the VLAN 5 or 10 networks seemingly will not pass over the network as I cannot even ping the gateway for each of these.  I have tried both static and dynamic addresses for the VLAN ID tagged traffic, no help.

Here is an illustration of what works.

[image]

And what does not work.

[image]

Where should I be looking?  There has to be something I am overlooking here, it seems like this would be a very common setup, but I feel like I may have been looking at this for too long.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to finally get this resolved.  The physical NIC I was using somehow had an issue with VLAN tagging.  I swapped the NIC's, reconfigured everything and then the VLAN ID's started working correctly.